# Detect checkbox that has been checked only when a next button is clicked

Tags: jquery

I've created a step by step test with checkboxes

This function skips to the next question:

```
  $('button.next').click(function(e) {
    // prevent the next buttons from submitting the form
    e.preventDefault();
    // hide this form-row, and show the next one
    $(this).parents('div.form-row').hide().next('div.form-row').show();
  });
```

This function detects which checkbox has been checked and whether it was right or wrong... in turn colouring progress circles for each question.

```
$('.correct').change(function(){
    var item = $(this).data('progress');
if ($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).hasClass('correct-answer')) {
        $('.quiz-progress-circle[data-progress="' + item + '"]').removeClass("progress-incorrect");
        $('.quiz-progress-circle[data-progress="' + item + '"]').addClass("progress-correct");
} else {
        $('.quiz-progress-circle[data-progress="' + item + '"]').removeClass("progress-correct");
  $('.quiz-progress-circle[data-progress="' + item + '"]').addClass("progress-incorrect");
}
});
```

At the moment this works "live" so you can just check each box and see if the progress circle for the question turns red or green - therefore creating an easy way to cheat. That isn't the intention.

How can I fire the correct answer detection only when the next button is clicked? There's no way to go back to a previous question so once they check their answers and click next it's very final.

---

Update:

```
  $('button.next').click(function(e) {
    // prevent the next buttons from submitting the form
    e.preventDefault();
    // hide this form-row, and show the next one


            var item = $(this).parents('div.form-row').find('.correct').data('progress');
        if ($(this).parents('div.form-row').find('.correct').is(":checked") && $(this).parents('div.form-row').find('.correct').hasClass('correct-answer')) {
                $('.quiz-progress-circle[data-progress="' + item + '"]').removeClass("progress-incorrect");
                $('.quiz-progress-circle[data-progress="' + item + '"]').addClass("progress-correct");
        } else {
                $('.quiz-progress-circle[data-progress="' + item + '"]').removeClass("progress-correct");
          $('.quiz-progress-circle[data-progress="' + item + '"]').addClass("progress-incorrect");
        }



    $(this).parents('div.form-row').hide().next('div.form-row').show();
  });
```

This always marks the progress circle as correct, not sure where it's going wrong?

Comment: so you just want to know how to check if button is clicked?

Comment: @vincent-d I'm not sure it's that simple... I want to check whether the previous answers were correct once the next button is clicked. Maybe I'm overthinking this.

Comment: you are, I do an answer

Comment: btw, we just have to press f12 on browser to see if an answer is correct or not because you use class and javascript to check all of this. So, if it's to learn jquery/javascript it's ok, but if it's for a live website/application, don't do that and look at ajax instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with the help of [vincent-d's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55847420). Here is the final, working code:

```
  $('button.next, input.check').click(function(e) {
    // prevent the next buttons from submitting the form
    e.preventDefault();

        var item = $(this).parents('div.form-row').find('.correct:first').data('progress');
    if ($(this).parents('div.form-row').find('.correct:first').is(":checked") && $(this).parents('div.form-row').find('.correct:first').hasClass('correct-answer')) {
            $('.quiz-progress-circle[data-progress="' + item + '"]').removeClass("progress-incorrect");
            $('.quiz-progress-circle[data-progress="' + item + '"]').addClass("progress-correct");
    } else {
            $('.quiz-progress-circle[data-progress="' + item + '"]').removeClass("progress-correct");
      $('.quiz-progress-circle[data-progress="' + item + '"]').addClass("progress-incorrect");
    }

    // hide this form-row, and show the next one
    $(this).parents('div.form-row').hide().next('div.form-row').show();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

So basicaly what you want is to change your approach so the code is fired when the next button is clicked

Actually, when next button is clicked, you go to next step, so I presume you want to show a green 'Correct answer!' modal somewhere

```
$('button.next').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // I do the check here instead of when the checkbox is checked
  if($('.correct:checked').hasClass('correct-answer')) {
    $('.red,.green').hide();  
    $('.green').show();
  }
  else{
    $('.red,.green').hide();  
    $('.red').show();
  }

  $(this).parents('div.form-row').hide().next('div.form-row').show();


});
```

be sure to add 2 title/div/p (as you want), one with class red and the other green
with text inside ("answer incorrect", "answer correct")